# WPF: Binding Property from User Control to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have a UserControl named AntecedentControl:

The XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Name="AntecedentUserControl">

<ScrollViewer DataContext="{Binding ElementName=AntecedentUserControl}">
    <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AntecedentList}"
                         AutoGenerateColumns="False"

        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Section, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        Header="Seccion"
                                        IsVisible="True"
                                        IsFilterable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Group, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    Header="Grupo"
                                    IsVisible="True"
                                    IsFilterable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Tome, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    Header="Tomo"
                                    IsVisible="True"
                                    IsFilterable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Volume, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    Header="Volumen"
                                    IsVisible="True"
                                    IsFilterable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Inscription, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    Header="Inscripcion"
                                    IsVisible="True"
                                    IsFilterable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Bis, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    Header="Bis"
                                    IsVisible="True"
                                    IsFilterable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewColumn>
                <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadButton Content="Delete"
                                           Command="telerikGrid:RadGridViewCommands.Delete"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewColumn>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

    </telerik:RadGridView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The code-behind (C#):

```
public partial class AntecedentControl : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<Antecedent> AntecedentList
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Antecedent>)GetValue(AntecedentListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AntecedentListProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AntecedentListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AntecedentList",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<Antecedent>),
        typeof(AntecedentControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Antecedent>(), OnListPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnListPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var antecedentList = source as AntecedentControl;
        var value = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<Antecedent>;
        antecedentList.AntecedentList = value;
    }

    public AntecedentControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And, on a separate view, I am calling this UserControl, like this:

```
<DomainTransmissionControls:AntecedentControl AntecedentList="{Binding ElementName=AntecedentUserControl, Path=Antecedents, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

On the ViewModel of this separate view, I have a Property called 'Antecedents':

```
public ObservableCollection<Antecedent> Antecedents { get; set; }
```

In simple words: The AntecedentControl UC is a grid that has a method where you can add/edit items on said grid. The property 'AntecedentList' of the current UC is where the list is being 'saved'.

The property 'Antecedents' of the ViewModel of the other UC where the 'AntecedentControl' is being called should be bound to 'AntecedentList' of AntecedentControl UC.

I would like to know how I can bind this property on the ViewModel to the property 'AntecedentList' property found in the separate UserControl (AntecedentControl), since this current code returns null.

I believe there is something wrong with my DependencyProperty declaration on the AntecedentControl UC, since putting a breakpoint on the 'OnListPropertyChanged' method reveals e.NewValue is returning null.

If so, why is not returning the default value declared in the Dependency Property statement?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just a note: your `OnListPropertyChanged` is redundant, because it only sets the value of the property once again. A dependency property changed callback is called when a property value has already changed. You don't have to set the value again.

Comment: In addition, you should not use a collection instance as default value of your dependency property. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970563.aspx#initializing) for an explanation.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the comments, but about the default value, this should not be a Read-Only Dependency Property, so setting it like in the article you posted breaks my code, cause I need the UC to be able to add/edit items inside the other UC.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the property is read-only or not. You would still have to set it in your UserControl's constructor, preferably by `SetCurrentValue(AntecedentListProperty, new ObservableCollection<Antecedent>());`.

Comment: I've tried many different ways to set that in the constructor, but it keeps breaking my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding appears to be incorrect. You appear to be attempting to access an element(AntecedentUserControl) that is inside the UserControl you've created?

Unless you've left out some code for simplicities sake, it actually seems like you don't even need a DependencyProperty? Is there any reason you can't set the DataContext?

**SomeView.xaml**

```
<DomainTransmissionControls:AntecedentControl DataContext="{Binding Antecedents}" />
```

**SomeViewModel.cs**

```
private ObservableCollection<Antecedent> _antecedents;

public ObservableCollection<Antecedent> Antecedents
{
    get
    {
        if (_antecedents == null)
            _antecedents = new ObservableCollection<Antecedent>();

        return _antecedents;
    }
}
```

**AntecedentControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl>
    <ScrollViewer>
       <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Section, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                            Header="Seccion" IsFilterable="False" IsVisible="True" />
                <!-- Additional column definitions. -->
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

**AntecedentControl.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class AntecedentControl : UserControl
{
    public AntecedentControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: I also thought this could be resolved like a regular binding, but it keeps bringing me null every time I set the breakpoint to validate this. I've tried your solution, but to no avail. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: @Xanagandr Are you certain you need a DependencyProperty at all? Have you left out code for the sake of brevity? Check out my new suggestion.

Comment: Yep, if I try to use a normal property setting, when binding the properties together I get an exception that states that you can only bind properties to Dependency Properties. I've also tried your example, but it is still not returning the values from the AntecedentControl property.